Does Mika successfully kill anyone during Run for the Money?
In episode 28 of Run for the Money: The Great Mission, it's revealed that the contestant Mika Lelouch is a serial killer who entered Run for the Money in order to sabotage other contestants.
In a flashback it's shown she killed a nurse before the game began, and she's shown attacking several players during the Run for the Money game, but does she actually kill anyone during the game? Is the nurse the only person Mika has successfully killed?
